# php mysql else on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a mysql table

table1

With the columns

task1, task2, task3

If a task has been completed it will contain a 1 if not than its a 0

I than have a table

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Progress</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Task 1 </td>
    <td><span class="badge bg-red">Error - Please Check</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>Task 2</td>
    <td><span class="badge bg-green">Completed</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.</td>
    <td>Task 3</td>
    <td><span class="badge bg-green">Completed</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i correctly write my php so it will Echo Completed if a task = 1 or Error if a task = 0 ?

Comment: `if ($row['task1']) { ... } else { ... }` WTP?

Comment: What if there's a fourth task!?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>Task 1 </td>
        <td><span class="badge 
            <?php
            if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
                echo "bg-green";
            } else {
                echo "bg-red";
            }
            ?>">
          <?php
          if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
              echo "Completed";
          } else {
              echo "Error - Please Check";
          }
          ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>Task 2</td>
        <td><span class="badge <?php
            if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
                echo "bg-green";
            } else {
                echo "bg-red";
            }
            ?>">
        <?php
          if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
              echo "Completed";
          } else {
              echo "Error - Please Check";
          }
          ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>Task 3</td>
        <td><span class="badge <?php
                  if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
                      echo "bg-green";
                  } else {
                      echo "bg-red";
                  }
                  ?>">
              <?php
              if ($row['task1'] == 1) {
                  echo "Completed";
              } else {
                  echo "Error - Please Check";
              }
              ?></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```